# Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4-M2

Tags: kotlin, plugins

why!!.. is there a solution?
this happens after update.

> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4-M2.
> Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4-M2/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4-M2.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4-M2/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4-M2.pom

Answer (score 2):

It's because obviously milestone releases of Kotlin Gradle Plugin are not yet published to release repositories.

Your second link is actually a redirect: `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4-M2/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4-M2.pom` → `https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4-M2/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4-M2.pom`. As you see, it points to the `libs-release-bintray` repo, which, as stated in its name, hosts only stable release.

You need to add an EAP repository to you build script, because the plugin you're looking for is actually located here: `https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4-M2`

Read more about configuring EAP in Gradle for Kotlin [here](https://kotlinlang.org/eap/configure-build-for-eap.html#adjust-the-kotlin-version-and-add-the-eap-repository).

Answer (score 2):

Add the following repository to your root `build.gradle` for milestone releases

```
  ext.kotlin_version = "1.4-M2"
  repositories {
    //Your existing respositories
    maven {
      url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/"
    }
  }
```

Comment: bintray is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Just add  mavenCentral() in buildscript

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. ext.Kotlin_version did not match the IDE version.